# No se visualizan los archivos adjuntos de imagen

Tags: php, archivo

Tengo el siguiente codigo que es para **adjuntar archivos** cuando el usuario envia correos.

Lo raro es que una vez que lo envia, luego no se puede visualizar correctamente los archivos de imagen (un archivo txt funciona bien).

### y aparece el aviso cuando se intenta visualizar:

### 'Formato de archivo No es compatible.'

Tengo que decir que si voy a la base de datos del servidor puedo visualizar perfectamente cualquier archivo (incluso los de imagen)

El directorio 'attachments' que es donde se alojan los archivos adjuntos tiene permisos 777, y los archivos se alojan bien en este directorio.

---

```
session_start();
require_once ('init.php');
if (!$login) {
    die(LANG_ERROR_DENIED);
}
if (!isset($_GET['file'])) {
    header('Location: .');
    die;
}
$dir = $db_settings['attachment_dir'];
$filename = basename($_GET['file']);
if (($filename == '.') || ($filename == '..') || ($filename == '')) {
    header('Location: .');
    die;
}
if (!file_exists($dir . $filename)) {
    die(LANG_ERROR_NOTFOUND);
}
$ext = substr(strrchr($filename, '.'), 1);
switch (strtolower($ext)) {
    case 'txt':
        $ctype = 'text/plain';
    break;
    case 'pdf':
        $ctype = 'application/pdf';
    break;
    case 'gif':
        $ctype = 'image/gif';
    break;
    case 'png':
        $ctype = 'image/png';
    break;
    case 'jpg':
        $ctype = 'image/jpg';
    break;
    default:
        $ctype = 'application/force-download';
}
header('Pragma: public');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Cache-Control: public');
header("Content-Type: $ctype");
$user_agent = strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
if ((is_integer(strpos($user_agent, 'msie'))) && (is_integer(strpos($user_agent, 'win')))) {
    header('Content-Disposition: filename=' . urlencode($filename) . ';');
} else {
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . urlencode($filename) . ';');
}
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($dir . $filename));
readfile($dir . $filename);
exit();
```

Comment: haz un echo de $dir.$filename para ver que te esta escribiendo. Puede ser que te falte un / o algo de eso?

Comment: Hola Gracias por contestar, no es eso, debido a que cargo un archivo txt y lo abre perfectamente. En cambio uno de imagen me da error...''Formato de archivo No es compatible.'